# How do I use MAGMI Column mapper for attributes with the same value?

Tags: product, magmi

The title speaks for itself.

I'm not able to configure magmi column mapper plugin for writing only one csv cell for attributes that are having the same value. IE: `image, small_image and thumbnail or name and product_name`.

So, can anyone tell me how to do this? I want ***my CSV file to be as clean and optimized as it can be made.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better use plugin "value replacer" for this purpose.

Column mapper has a bit different aim - to map columns. For example if your supplier's csv has a column for "ean" and you want it to map to "sku".

As for value replacer, here is how it's done:

**Replaced attributes**: small_image,thumbnail

**small_image**: {{ '{item.small_image}' == '' ? '{item.image}' : '{item.small_image}'}}
**thumbnail**: {{ '{item.thumbnail}' == '' ? '{item.image}' : '{item.thumbnail}'}}

This will make *small_image* and *thumbnail* similar to *"image"* field unless explicitly assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to stay with Column Mapper you may just enter all three columns `image,small_image,thumbnail` into the `New name for col Image` field. It works on `Column mapper v0.0.3`.

Answer (score 0):

tzvi's answer is correct. This is an attempt to improve. This plugin has 2 behaviors. You can rename a column or replicate a column.

EXAMPLES:
With:

```
Colums Mapped list: full_name

New name for col name: name
```

You will be changing the name of the column.

With:

```
Colums Mapped list: name

New name for col name: name, short_description
```

You're keeping the name's column (name) and also duplicating the column with a new name (short_description)